# Node.js child-process crashing after a lot of console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, console.log

I'm working on an application where a central node-process starts various child-node-processes. I'm having problems with the child process exiting after a lot of console-output (no matter if it's redirected to the parent process or not).

I could reduce the problem to a simple two-file-setup:

- If I run "node child.js" it runs without any problem.
- If I run "node server.js" this process starts the child.js as well, but it returns with code "null" after 16615 "console.log"-outputs.

  The node.exe still runs for a while an consumes up to 1500MB RAM. (Running "node child.js" takes a maximum of 650 MB.)

Code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e7797d277770eeb1d1db20a0363c9d0a

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

---

Node Versions: 6.11.1 and 8.2.1 on Windows 10 x64.

**parent.js**

```
var child = require('child_process');

console.log('parent (PID ' + process.pid + ': starting child');
var proc = child.exec('node child.js');
console.log('parent: stated child');
proc.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
proc.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
proc.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log('parent: child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

**child.js**

```
console.log('child: i have been started - PID ' + process.pid);
for (var i = 1; i < 3000000; i++){
    console.log('child: ' + i);
}
console.log('child: i have finished');
```

Comment: [`exec` buffers all the child process’s output](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback); you probably want `spawn`. Also, please edit your question to include the code directly rather than linking to a Gist.

Comment: Please provide Node.js Version + OS.

Comment: Replacing `exec` by `spawn` solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably exceeding the default limit of maxBuffer.
As a second parameter to your child process, add `{ maxBuffer: 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}` to increase the maxBuffer:

> child.exec('node child.js', { maxBuffer: 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024})